# Why can't I compile an unordered_map with a pair as key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map, keyvaluepair

I am trying to create an `unordered_map` to map pairs with integers:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using Vote = pair<string, string>;
using Unordered_map = unordered_map<Vote, int>;
```

I have a class where I have declared an `Unordered_map` as a private member.

However, I am getting the following error when I try to compile it:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:948:38: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash, std::__1::basic_string > >'

I am not getting this error if I use a regular map like `map<pair<string, string>, int>` instead of an `unordered_map`.

Is it not possible to use `pair` as key in unordered maps?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You need to provide a suitable hash function for your key type. A simple example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// Only for pairs of std::hash-able types for simplicity.
// You can of course template this struct to allow other hash functions
struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator () (const std::pair<T1,T2> &p) const {
        auto h1 = std::hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        auto h2 = std::hash<T2>{}(p.second);

        // Mainly for demonstration purposes, i.e. works but is overly simple
        // In the real world, use sth. like boost.hash_combine
        return h1 ^ h2;  
    }
};

using Vote = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using Unordered_map = std::unordered_map<Vote, int, pair_hash>;

int main() {
    Unordered_map um;
}
```

This will work, but not have the best hash-properties<sup>†</sup>. You might want to have a look at something like [`boost.hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/hash/combine.html) for higher quality results when combining the hashes. This is also discussed in greater detail – including the aforementioned solution from boost – in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689/3002139).

For real world use: Boost also provides the function set [`hash_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/hash/reference.html) which already provides a hash function for `std::pair`, as well as `std::tuple` and most standard containers.

---

<sup>†</sup>More precisely, it will produce too many collisions. E.g., every symmetric pair will hash to 0 and pairs that differ only by permutation will have the same hash. This is probably fine for your programming exercise, but might seriously hurt performance of real world code.

Comment: You reference `hash_value` but the link goes to `hash`. I think `hash` is the correct location because docs for `hash_value` recommend using `hash`. I thought I would let you edit rather than doing it myself...

Comment: @PeterVermont `hash_value` is documented on the page I link. Do you have a better link?

Comment: @Baum mit Augean The link is correct but I suggest that the text of the link say 'hash' rather than 'hash_value'

Comment: Careful: "pairs that differ only by permutation will have the same hash". To put it more bluntly: `pair_hash({a, b}) ==pair_hash({b, a})` is rarely what you want! (The culprit is the XOR. `return h1 ^(h2 << 1);` should fix it.)

Comment: @Unapiedra That's slightly better, but still not great; e.g. the hashes of permuted will still be fairly close to each other. There are questions on this site on how to do it right.

Comment: Is there an example of how 'pair_hash' comparator can be written as a Lambda function (c++11 onwards) in the declaration of unordered_map 'um' ???

Comment: @JoeBlack I'm not so sure I would endorse that from a readability point of view, especially when we move from this trivial example to an actually useful hash combiner. But if you insist: [Lambda expressions as class template parameters](//stackoverflow.com/q/5849059)

Answer (score 37):

My preferred way of solving this problem is to define a `key` function that transforms your pair into a unique integer (or any hashable data type). This key is not the hash key. It is the unique ID of the pair of data that will then be optimally hashed by the `unordered_map`. For example, you wanted to define an `unordered_map` of the type

```
  unordered_map<pair<int,int>,double> Map;
```

And you want to use `Map[make_pair(i,j)]=value` or `Map.find(make_pair(i,j))` to operate on the map. Then you'll have to tell the system how to hash a pair of integers `make_pair(i,j)`. Instead of that, we can define

```
  inline size_t key(int i,int j) {return (size_t) i << 32 | (unsigned int) j;}
```

and then change the type of the map to

```
  unordered_map<size_t,double> Map;
```

We can now use `Map[key(i,j)]=value` or `Map.find(key(i,j))` to operate on the map. Every `make_pair` now becomes calling the inline `key` function.

This method guarantees that the key will be optimally hashed, because now the hashing part is done by the system, which will always choose the internal hash table size to be prime to make sure every bucket is equally likely. But you have to make yourself 100% sure that the `key` is unique for every pair, i.e., no two distinct pairs can have the same key, or there can be very difficult bugs to find.

Comment: Good luck doing that for `pair<string,string>` as OP wants.

Comment: Even if the OP wants to do that for `pair<string,string>` - this is nevertheless a good way doing this for `pair<int,int>` because `key` is bijective. May help someone!

Comment: @Zhuoran He I just wanna confirm something, this inline function only works for 64 bit systems right? As far as my understanding goes, this will fail on a 32 bit system for a pair of ints, right?

Comment: Since `size_t` isn't guaranteed to be 64-bit, you should use `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: I agree with @lukasl1991, this is a good idea.  I made it independent of the arch size like this.  It works efficiently for the common case where the ints (generally) fit in a short on 32 bit systems or in 4 bytes on systems where size_t is 8 bytes:
`code`
struct Pair_Hash {
  inline size_t operator() (const std::pair<int, int> &pair) const {
    return pair.first + (pair.second << (sizeof(size_t) * 8 / 2));
  }
};
`code`

Answer (score 23):

If using `pair` is not a strict requirement, you can simply use map twice.

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using Unordered_map = unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int>>;

Unordered_map um;
um["Region1"]["Candidate1"] = 10;
cout << um["Region1"]["Candidate1"];    // 10
```

Comment: how to write the range-based for loop here

Comment: This will require two hash-table lookups instead of just one. Thus, it will significantly degrade performance if the table is accessed frequently, e.g. if used as a cache of some sorts. On the other hand, the readability is much better!

Comment: The solution is simple and reasonable hash functions are likely to be used for each hash-table lookup. While the performance hit from a poorly chosen or a poorly implemented custom hash function could be even worse than from the double lookup.

Answer (score 21):

For pair key, we can use boost pair hash function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  unordered_map<pair<string, string>, int, boost::hash<pair<string, string>>> m;

  m[make_pair("123", "456")] = 1;
  cout << m[make_pair("123", "456")] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Similarly we can use boost hash for vectors,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  unordered_map<vector<string>, int, boost::hash<vector<string>>> m;
  vector<string> a({"123", "456"});

  m[a] = 1;
  cout << m[a] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `boost::hash` does not seem to be available for tuples, sadly.

Answer (score 6):

Reference: [C++ Standard Library: A tutorial and reference, Second version](https://www.mica.edu.vn/perso/Vu-Hai/EE3490/Ref/The%20C++Standard%20Library%20-%202nd%20Edition.pdf) Chapter 7.9.2: Creating and Controlling unordered Container

All solutions I found in Google use `XOR` to generate hashcode of `pair`, which is totally bad. see [why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes). However, the book has given us the best solution, using `hash_combine`, which is taken from `Boost`. The solution is much better than XOR when I tested it in Online Judge([Atcoder](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc168/tasks/abc168_e)). I organized the code as a template as follow. You can copy and paste it as much as you can. And it is convenient to change it to fit any custom struct/class.

Update: add hash template for tuple.

```cpp
#include <functional>

namespace hash_tuple {
template <typename TT> struct hash {
    size_t operator()(TT const &tt) const { return std::hash<TT>()(tt); }
};

// from boost (functional/hash):
// see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html template
template <class T> inline void hash_combine(std::size_t &seed, T const &v) {
    seed ^= hash_tuple::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

// Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
struct HashValueImpl {
    void operator()(size_t &seed, Tuple const &tuple) const {
        HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index - 1>{}(seed, tuple);
        hash_combine(seed, std::get<Index>(tuple));
    }
};
template <class Tuple> struct HashValueImpl<Tuple, 0> {
    void operator()(size_t &seed, Tuple const &tuple) const {
        hash_combine(seed, std::get<0>(tuple));
    }
};

template <typename... TT> struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> {
    size_t operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const &tt) const {
        size_t seed = 0;
        HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...>>{}(seed, tt);
        return seed;
    }
};
// auxiliary generic functions to create a hash value using a seed
template <typename T> inline void hash_val(std::size_t &seed, const T &val) {
    hash_combine(seed, val);
}

template <typename T, typename... Types>
inline void hash_val(std::size_t &seed, const T &val, const Types &... args) {
    hash_combine(seed, val);
    hash_val(seed, args...);
}

template <typename... Types>
inline std::size_t hash_val(const Types &... args) {
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    hash_val(seed, args...);
    return seed;
}

struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) const {
        return hash_val(p.first, p.second);
    }
};
} // namespace hash_tuple

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    using ll = long long;
    // std::unordered_map<std::pair<ll, ll>, ll, hash_tuple::pair_hash>
    // hashmapPair; std::unordered_set<std::pair<ll, ll>, hash_tuple::pair_hash>
    // hashsetPair;

    std::unordered_map<std::pair<ll, ll>, ll, hash_tuple::pair_hash>
        hashmapPair;
    hashmapPair[{0, 0}] = 10;
    std::unordered_set<std::pair<ll, ll>, hash_tuple::pair_hash> hashsetPair;
    hashsetPair.insert({1, 1});

    using TI = std::tuple<ll, ll, ll, ll>;
    std::unordered_map<TI, ll, hash_tuple::hash<TI>> hashmapTuple;
    hashmapTuple[{0, 1, 2, 3}] = 10;
    std::unordered_set<TI, hash_tuple::hash<TI>> hashsetTuple;
    hashsetTuple.emplace(0, 1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As your compilation error indicates, there is no valid instantiation of `std::hash<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` in your std namespace.

According to my compiler:

> Error C2338   The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this
>   type. c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   14.0\vc\include\xstddef   381

You can provide your own specialization for `std::hash<Vote>` as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using Vote = pair<string, string>;
using Unordered_map = unordered_map<Vote, int>;

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Vote>
    {
        size_t operator()(Vote const& v) const
        {
            // ... hash function here ...
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    Unordered_map m;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `const Vote& v`

Comment: @GuyKogus "const Vote&" and "Vote const&" are exactly the same.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after

Comment: I think [this is Undefined Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std): It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template.

Answer (score 3):

I've simplified @YoungForest's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62035742/237105) to only work with pairs (= not with arbitrary length tuples) as was requested by the OP. I've also minimized the boilerplate code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>       # pair

using namespace std;

// from boost (functional/hash):
// see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html template
template <class T> inline void hash_combine(size_t &seed, T const &v) {
    seed ^= hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator()(const pair<T1, T2> &p) const {
        size_t seed = 0;
        hash_combine(seed, p.first);
        hash_combine(seed, p.second);
        return seed;
    }
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int, pair_hash> d;
    d[{1, 2}] = 3;
    cout << d.find({1, 2})->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It uses the same logic as in the boost library (that is better than the xor version).

Answer (score 2):

In the comments on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685618/2675154) by *Baum mit Augen*, the user *Joe Black* [asked for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/unordered-map-with-pair-as-key-not-compiling#comment87894973_32685618) on using a [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a hash function. I agree with the [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/unordered-map-with-pair-as-key-not-compiling#comment87902375_32685618) of *Baum mit Augen*, that this might harm readability, especially if you want to implement a more universal solution. Therefore, I'd like to keep my example short by focusing on a specific solution for `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, as presented by the OP. The example also uses a [handcrafted](https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers) combination of `std::hash<std::string>` function calls:

```
using Vote = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
auto hash = [](const Vote& v){
    return std::hash<std::string>()(v.first) * 31 + std::hash<std::string>()(v.second);
};
using Unordered_map = std::unordered_map<Vote, int, decltype(hash)>;
Unordered_map um(8, hash);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/35ZDLF)

Answer (score 2):

There is a **hack** to such problems

Use a `std:unordered_map` of `string`

Look at the following example-

I am required to hash the endpoint(corner) of a rectangle

> Error Approach

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int> M;           //ERROR

pair<int, int> p;
M[p]++;
```

> Hack

```
unordered_map<string, int> M;

pair<int, int> p;
string s = to_string(p.first) + "_" + to_string(p.second);
M[s]++;
```

Such hack even works if you are required to create a hash of decimal or double as a key :)

Comment: What if those strings in the original key contained underscores `_`, too?