# How to correctly get value from unordered map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have such unordered map:

```
static std::unordered_map<std::pair<size_t , size_t>, long> my_map;
```

Then I want to get value from `my_map`:

```
size_t size1 = 1;
size_t size2 = 2;
auto x = make_pair(size1, size2);
auto &result = my_map[x];
```

But I have an error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, long int>’ and ‘std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>’)
     auto &result = my_map[x];
```

How can I overcome it?

Comment: Use a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hm, in my example I used `static std::unordered_map<std::pair<size_t , size_t>, long>`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ shouldn't it work anyway?

Comment: Works for me out of the box if I define hash for a pair.

Comment: @kotokbek http://ideone.com/tZmsA1 I see the same error, but also an error for the lack of a hash. If you define a hash it may go away.

Comment: See hash function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32685618/1460794)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hash function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685618/1460794):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

// Only for pairs of std::hash-able types for simplicity.
// You can of course template this struct to allow other hash functions
struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator () (const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) const {
        auto h1 = std::hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        auto h2 = std::hash<T2>{}(p.second);

        // Mainly for demonstration purposes, i.e. works but is overly simple
        // In the real world, use sth. like boost.hash_combine
        return h1 ^ h2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //static std::unordered_map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, long> my_map;
    static std::unordered_map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, long, pair_hash> my_map;

    size_t size1 = 1;
    size_t size2 = 2;
    auto x = std::make_pair(size1, size2);
    auto &result = my_map[x];

    return 0;

}
```