# Which data structure to use to store edges of graph so that I can access edge weight in constant time in c++?

Tags: c++, graph, graph-theory

I am using an adjacency list to store a graph. Since I am using adjacency list, I cannot access edge weight of a graph in constant time. So, I wonder which EXTRA data structure to use only to story edges indexed by the two nodes u and v?

Currently, I am trying with `map<pair<int, int>, int>` but it has log (N) complexity and `unordered_map` does not have a policy for `pairs`. I know that, an edge weight is independent of the order of {u,v}, but I am not able to use this feature anyhow.

Comment: try using 2d array

Comment: _"unordered_map does not have a policy for pairs"_ Make one or use Boost's https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685540/560648

Comment: Adjacency matrix is not feasible as Of(n^2) complexity

Answer (score 0):

Use an adjacency matrix; a 2D array where each element in the `array[x][y]` is the weight of the edge between nodes `x` and `y`.

Comment: It's possible/likely that the OP is using an adjacency list because the O(N^2) memory of an array is prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple solution would be to create an array that stores the outgoing edges for each node plus the weight. You'd simply jump to one node, search the other node in it's outgoing edges and take the weight. Complexity is maximal degree, which I usually assume to be capped.

Only thing to make sure is that all the redundant information is kept consistent.

Like

```
class AdjacentWeightedEdges {

    struct OutgoingWeightedEdge {
        size_t target_node;
        int weight;
    }

    vector<OutgoingWeightedEdge> edges;
    int edge_weight(const size_t index) const {
        iterate through edges
        if an edge with index found, return it's weight
        raise an error if not
    }
}

class Graph {

    //your stuff as it is right inserted here

    vector<AdjacentWeightedEdges> adjacencies;

    int edge_weight(const size_t index_1, const size_t index_2){
        return adjacencies[index_1].edge_weight(index_2);
    }
}
```

If even a 1d approach like this creates memory problems, consider only storing the edges for index_1 < index_2.

Another similar method:

Store an array of pointers to the nodes, have the edge weights in the adjacency list and do what I did directly. If you don't go with indices anyhow if memory is a problem.

Another answer here talks about the adjacency matrix - this one could even work if a certain structure for a sparse matrix class is used that stores first non-zero in row/column pointers and then pointers to every following non-zero entry. Although this essentially collapses to my approach. Might be worthwhile if you need a sparse matrix class anyway.