# error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<>'

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

How do I create a hash function for key as pair of string and enum to be used in unordered_map?

I have the following pair which is the key to an unordered map how do I create a hash so it can be used in unordered_map?

```
enum Color {
Red,
Green
};

typedef std::pair <std::string, Color>
```

I tried the following but got compilation error

```
struct EnumClassHash
{
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(T t) const
    {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(t);
    }
};
size_t hash( const PairType & pair ) {
    return std::hash<std::string>()(pair.first) ^
           std::hash<EnumClassHash>()(pair.second);
}

typedef std::unordered_map<PairType, std::string>, 
    std::function<decltype(hash)>> ColorMapType;
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<EnumClassHash>'
            std::hash<EnumClassHash>()(pairType.second);
```

The following isnt working either

```
size_t hash( const PairType & pairType ) {
    return std::hash<std::string>()(pairType.first) ^
           std::hash<Color>()(pairType.second);
}


 typedef std::unordered_map<PairType, std::string, \
    std::function<decltype(hash)>> ColorMapType;

ColorMapType colorMap(100, hash);
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<Color>'
            std::hash<Color>()(pair.second
```

);

PS Pardon my formatting. I lost my gmail password and can only post from mobile app which is a tiny screen.

Comment: What's the point of `EnumClassHash`, exactly?

Comment: @StoryTeller to write the hash function. Do you have suggestion for alternative solution?

Comment: Yes, `std::hash<Color>`. The standard library already handles all scoped and unscoped enumeration types.

Comment: does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/unordered-map-with-pair-as-key-not-compiling?lq=1

Comment: @StoryTeller See my updated post. Using std::hash<Color> still has compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you declare `struct EnumClassHash`, it is its own thing, not a specialization of `std::hash`.
- When you write `std::hash<EnumClassHash>()(pair.second)`, the template specialization `std::hash<EnumClassHash>` simply doesn't exist.

You can either:

- declare `struct EnumClassHash`, and use `EnumClassHash`, or
- specialize `std::hash` into `std::hash<Color>`, and use `std::hash<Color>`, or
- do both,

but never mix and match part of each method, which does not make any kind of sense.

Also, to use `std::pair<std::string, Color>` as the key type of `std::unordered_map`, neither `std::hash<Color>` nor `EnumClassHash` matters. What matters is `std::hash<std::pair<std::string, Color>>` or your own class that hashes `std::pair<std::string, Color>`.

---

Here is a recipe you can follow.

To use `std::pair<std::string, Color>` as key type, you need to specialize `std::hash<std::pair<std::string, Color>>` yourself.

```
template <>
struct std::hash<std::pair<std::string, Color>>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<std::string, Color>& p) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(p.first) ^ std::hash<Color>()(p.second);
    }
};
```

But before that, you need to specialize `std::hash<Color>` first since `std::hash<std::pair<std::string, Color>>` uses it.

```
template <>
struct std::hash<Color>
{
    std::size_t operator()(Color c) const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(c);
    }
};
```

Then, you can use something like `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, Color>, std::string>`. No `EnumClassHash` involved.

---

If you love `EnumClassHash` very much, here is another recipe.

You can keep `EnumClassHash` as you like.

```
struct EnumClassHash
{
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(T t) const
    {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(t);
    }
};
```

This time, `std::hash<Color>` does not exist. Don't use it. (Not to mention `std::hash<EnumClassHash>` which does not make sense.)

So, the class that hash the key type should use `EnumClassHash`. (Once again, not `std::hash<EnumClassHash>`!)

```
struct PairHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<std::string, Color>& p) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(p.first) ^ EnumClassHash()(p.second);
    }
};
```

Now, you can use `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, Color>, std::string, PairHash>`.

Comment: thats the part I cant get it working. see my updated post

Comment: @johnsam What do you mean by "that"?

Comment: Thanks only the second solution - EnumClassHas and PairHash worked for me. Had tons of compilation error on the first one.