# I'm intrested in finding the time complexity of a map with two keys

Tags: c++, hashmap, time-complexity

I am trying to convert the entire elements of a matrix in to a hashmap. for that what i tried is using `map<pair<int,int>,int>mp;`

where pair<int,int>  are the array indices and the value is the value in the element of a matrix.
so i tried this way
`mp[{i,j}]=value;`

It works fine but what i am interested in is finding the time complexity .In general if there and n keys maping to a value what will be the time complexity and how.

Comment: _"...Logarithmic in the size of the container...."_: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: A key of type `pair<int,int>` is still a single key, so your map is a map with one key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, **map** container in C++ is a tree-based structure. You mentioned using a hashmap. **unordered_map** is a hash-based container in C++.

As for the unordered_map (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map):

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value
> pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements
> have average constant-time complexity.

Comment: I got a clarifiation about map and unordered_map but in the above mentioned link i didn't get any information about hashmap with two keys or in general n keys

Comment: @Doddigirish  If 2 keys need 2 comparisons in Order Notation `O(n) + O(n)` is `2O(n)` which is `O(n)`.  Substitute the actual Order and number of keys into the above.

Comment: @Doddigirish If you mean how to use a pair as a key, for example, you need to provide a hash function for your key type. Please have a look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/why-cant-i-compile-an-unordered-map-with-a-pair-as-key)