# Creating unordered map in C++ for counting the pairs

Tags: c++, stl

So let's say I have an array, `1 2 1 2 3 4 2 1` and I want to store all the `(arr[i], arr[i-1)` such that `arr[i] != arr[i-1]` as a pair in unordered_map for counting these pairs.

For e.g.

```
(1, 2)  -> 2
(2, 3) -> 1
(3, 4) -> 1
(4, 2) -> 1
(2, 1) -> 1
```

So the syntax I tried,

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>,  int> umap;
int temp; 
cin>>temp;
arr[i]=temp;
for (int i=1; i< n; i++){
   cin>>temp;
   arr[i]=temp;
            
   umap[(arr[i-1], arr[i])]++;
}
```

Next thing, I also tried with proper definition.

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>,  int> umap;
cin>>temp;
arr[i]=temp;
for (int i=1; i< n; i++){
   cin>>temp;
   arr[i]=temp;
   pair<int, int> p(arr[i-1], arr[i]);
   umap[p]++;
}
```

Can anybody please help me get the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `unordered_map` with a `pair` because there is no default hash implemented.
You can however use `map` which should work fine for your purpose because `pair` does implement `<`.
See [Why can't I compile an unordered_map with a pair as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/why-cant-i-compile-an-unordered-map-with-a-pair-as-key) when you really want `unordered_map`.

You can construct `pair` with curly braces like this

```
umap[{arr[i-1], arr[i]}]++;
```

I think from C++11 onward, but it might be C++14 or even C++17

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is that [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) requires a hashable key type. (It's implemented as a hashmap)

But `std::hash` has no overload for `std::pair<>`, so your `std::unordered_map` doesn't compile.

---

###### using a normal `std::map`

You could fix this by either switching to a normal map which only requires `operator<`, which [is implemented by `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```cpp
std::map<std::pair<int, int>,  int> umap;

int values[] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1};
for (int i=1; i< sizeof(values) / sizeof(int); i++) {
    umap[std::pair(values[i-1], values[i])]++;
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/61hYW8GE4)

---

###### create a hash function

Or if you want to keep the hashmap, you need to provide a hashing function for your pair, e.g.:

```cpp
struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T, class U>
    std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T, U> const& pair) const {
        return std::hash<T>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(pair.second);
    }
};
```

and then use that for your map:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>,  int, pair_hash> umap;

int values[] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1};
for (int i=1; i< sizeof(values) / sizeof(int); i++) {
    umap[std::pair(values[i-1], values[i])]++;
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/vKqrc918T)

**Warning:** In this example the two hashes from the pair just get xor'ed. This is not a very good method to combine hashes in general, and you should replace it with a better function for production use, for example [this `hash_combine` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595226/8411406).