# How does memoization help here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I just solved the subset sum problem:

> Given an integer array `nums` of size `N`.  You are also given an integer `B`, you need to find whether there exists a subset in `nums` whose sum is `B`.  If there exist a subset then return `1` else return `0`.
>
> Constraints are: `1 <= N <= 100`; `1 <= nums[i] <= 100`; `1 <= B <= 10^5`;

The way I solved this problem is as below (0/1 knapsack):

```cpp
vector<int> n;
int t;
unordered_map<string, long long> m;

int helper(int i, int sum) {
    if(i>=n.size()) return sum==t;
    string str=to_string(i)+"-"+to_string(sum);
    if(m.count(str)) return m[str];

    int val=helper(i+1, sum+n[i]);
    val=max(val, helper(i+1, sum));

    return m[str]=val;
}

int Solution::solve(vector<int> &nums, int B) {
    n=nums;
    t=B;
    m.clear();
    
    return helper(0,0);
}
```

This gets "Accepted".  However, note that all the values in `nums` are positive; so IMO sum will only remain the same/go on increasing.  `i` goes on increasing, too.  So, we will never encounter a value previously stored in the memoization table.

But, if I remove memoization, it results in Wrong Answer for some large test case.  What am I missing?  Will any recursive call ever encounter a previous state?

Comment: Questions like this, where you can't provide the input that causes the failure, may be off topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270585/are-uva-online-judge-runtime-errors-off-topic.  You may have to do more work on developing your own test cases in order to create a [mcve] and make an acceptable question.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you.  I am just hoping to get the logical flaw in my understanding that we never encounter previously computed values.

Comment: Not really related, but `string str=to_string(i)+"-"+to_string(sum);`: Are you aware of `std::pair`?

Comment: `int val=helper(i+1, sum+n[i]); val=max(val, helper(i+1, sum));` the second call gets a smaller value of `sum` than the first one, so `sum` is certainly not monotone increasing.

Comment: You could test your claim by inserting `assert(m.find(str) == m.end())`...

Comment: Also, why use globals? You can pass the vector to your helper function by reference.

Comment: If your array is `2,4,1,5, ...`, and you choose 2,4 while skipping 1,5, then you have a subproblem with i=4 and sum=6. On the other hand, if you skip 2,4 and choose 1,5, then the subproblem is i=4 and sum=6.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes, but we cannot have an `unordered_map` with a `pair` as a key; so we need to use `map` instead.  This increases the time complexity without any benefit, since we don't want to keep them ordered (we just need efficient lookups).  Do you agree?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Someone: "we cannot have an unordered_map with a pair as a key": You can if you provide a hash function, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685618/634919

Answer (score 0):

You call `helper` twice, the second time with the lower `sum` than the first. Therefore a later call to `helper` could indeed have the same `sum` as an earlier call.

@user3386109 already gave a concrete set of `num` that demonstrates this.  As for how often, consider the case where `nums = [1, 1, ..., 1]` 100 times.  Then without memoization you'll call `helper(100, 50)` `100 choose 50 = 100,891,344,545,564,193,334,812,497,256` times.  Over 100 octillion calls..takes a while.