# Unordered map where key is a pair

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, std-pair

I have an unordered map where my key is a pair of <int, const Foo*> and value is a vector. I do not see any compilation or runtime error during insertion or lookup but I am not sure if this is most efficient code. Will the compiler create an efficient hash function for computing hash value of the key or should I use  boost::hash?

```
class Foo {
  public:
   Foo():var1(0){};
   ~Foo();
   void func(int a) {
      var1 = a;
   }
   int var1;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    f1.func(10);
    const Foo* fp = &f1;
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint,const Foo*>,std::vector<uint>> umap1;
    umap1[std::make_pair(1,fp)].emplace_back(100);
}
```

Comment: `Will the compiler create an efficient hash function for computing hash value of the key` no, c++ compiler never creates any hash functions

Comment: Why is it not failing during compile time? So, I should use boost to create a hash function?

Comment: it fails to compile, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/why-cant-i-compile-an-unordered-map-with-a-pair-as-key

Comment: So, I should use boost to create a hash function?

Comment: You don't need boost for creating hash function, see example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash.  
You'll also need function for keys comparison - but it is also covered in the link I provided

Comment: @TenerowiczS `==` works fine on pairs, so no need for that

Answer (score 0):

`std::hash<T>` has no `std::pair<X,Y>` specialization.  You have to provide one.

Boost's one isn't as bad as the first one you are likely to write, so feel free to use it.  (It isn't perfect, but it isn't horrid).

The hashing trick I use is to first start with an ADL helper:

```
namespace MyNS {
  template<class T, class...Unused>
  std::size_t hash( T const& t, Unused... )->decltype( std::hash<T>{}(std::declval<T const&>()) ) {
    return std::hash<T>{}(t);
  }
  struct hasher {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const& t)const {
      return hash(t);
    }
  }
}
```

as written, `MyNS::Hasher` passed to a `std::unordered_map<X,Y, MyNS::Hasher>` will invoke `std::hash<X>` as its hasher.

But if you override `hash` in the namespace of `X` or in `MyNS` you'll call it instead.  This allows us to extend stuff nicely.

```
namespace MyNS {
  std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs ) {
    return ((lhs<<6)+(lhs>>3)) + rhs;
  }
  template<class...Szs>
  std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t lhs ) {
    return lhs;
  }
  template<class...More>
  std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs, More...more ) {
    return hash_combine( hash_combine(lhs, rhs), more... );
  }

  template<class T, class U>
  std::size_T hash( std::pair<T, U> const& p ) {
    return hash_combine( hash(p.first), hash(p.second) );
  }
}
```

I then add this.  `hash_combine` can be written better (boost has an example of a better one), but it combines two size_t hashes into one.  But the above one is better than nothing.

It takes 1 or more arguments and combines their hashes into one hash.

I then add an overload to `hash` for `std::pair`  It invokes `hash` on its elements; this means pairs of pairs are supported.  We can add tuple support:

```
  template<std::size_t...Is, class Tup>
  std::size_T hash( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tup const& tup ) {
    return hash_combine( std::get<Is>(tup)... );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_T hash( std::tuple<Ts...> const& tup ) {
    return hash_combine( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, tup );
 }
```

and vector support:

```
 template<class Seq>
 std::size_t hash_sequence(Seq const& v) {
   std::size_t r = 0;
   for (auto const& e:v) {
     r = hash_combine( r, hash(e) );
   }
   return r;
 }
 template<class T, class A>
 std::size_t hash(std::vector<T,A> const& v) {
   return hash_sequence(v);
 }
```

and similar for other containers.

Any class you need to support hash for is easy:

```
namespace SomeRandomNS {
  struct some_random_type {
    int state;
  };
  inline std::size_t hash( some_random_type const& x ) {
    using MyNS::hash;
    return hash(x.state);
  }
}
```

and done.  For something more complex:

```
namespace SomeRandomNS {
  struct some_random_type {
    int state;
    double more_state;
    std::string even_more;
  };
  inline std::size_t hash( some_random_type const& x ) {
    using MyNS::hash;
    return hash(std::tie(x.state, x.more_state, x.even_more));
  }
}
```

and we are done (the tuple hash does the work for us).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what would be perfect way to implement this?

Comment: @Pirate Done as requested