# Accessing map with pair as the key

Tags: c++, stl

As the title said.
I'm new to c++.
So i wanted to make a map with pair of int as the key and boolean as the value

```
 map <pair<int,int>,bool>.
```

how do i assign the value and access it?

Comment: Same way you do any other map.  You pass a pair to it using `[]` or `find`.

Comment: so mymap[int,int]=value. ?

Comment: No.  How would you create a `pair`, pass a pair to a function?

Comment: i'm a little confused. how do i declare the map and use it(assign value, get the value)?

Comment: @FandyPutra e.g. like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9ae369118fa3fee)

Comment: kind of a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277172/using-pair-as-key-in-a-map-c-stl) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016646/using-pairint-int-as-key-for-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pair<int, int> as key for map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016646/using-pairint-int-as-key-for-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pair as key in a map (C++ / STL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277172/using-pair-as-key-in-a-map-c-stl)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass one `std::pair<int,int>` object (your comment suggests passing two `int` objects, but that's no pair *yet*.)

You can create a `std::pair<int,int>` like this: `std::pair<int,int> {5,7}` or figure out the types from the two arguments to `std::make_pair(5, 7)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in

```
map <pair<int,int>, bool> mp;
```

is a key of pair. Therefore you can assign a value and access it as -

```
mp[{1,2}] = true;
```